# liaison entre web3 et nodejs [using web3js and nodjs]

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nodejs

Bonjour,

j'ai développé une app avec nodejs et je voulais la transférer vers une dapp en intégrant le web3 librairie.

En effet j'ai crée les smart contract il le me reste juste la façon de faire la liaison entre le layout et le nodejs et webjs de tel façon qu'au moment du clique sur ajouter des données cela les envoie vers la blockchain en appelant la smart contract.

Merci

Comment: This community is English speaking. Your chances of getting responses would be massively higher if you rewrote your question in English.

Comment: vous pouvez élaborer plus pour avoir de l'aide (explique ce que tu'es entrain de faire et pose des example de code).je pense la documentation officiel  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API pourra t'aider. une dernierre chose une question en anglais est desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Vous n'avez pas posé de question, donc il est difficile d'y répondre.
Dans tous les cas, vous devriez regarder ici : 
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Malheureusement, je ne connais pas de référence en français.
Peut-être sur ethereum-france.org, sur la section francophone
de forum.ethereum.org, ou sur www.cryptofr.com ? Cela vous évitera les commentaires désagréables des anglomaniaques.

Bon courage.